# why percent sign is not accepted in some cases in xml-text field when xml is deserialized with C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

```
<name>Hello '"world", ü ë &amp%;</name>
<label>''MHU233%;'</label>
```

XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader) throws an InvalidOperationException in first case above. Would like to know what is wrong and why latter is ok. XmlReader is created with XmlSettings in constructor where Xml-schema is in SchemaSet.

Thanks!

Comment: i'm sorry but i cannot write the examples correctly. xml-tags are omitted.

Comment: Please provide a minimal XML file and the minimal compiling piece of relevant code.

Comment: Use &lt; &gt; or [ and ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got an invalid entity there:

```
&amp%;
```

It should be:

```
&amp;
```

The & says it's the start of an entity. There's no entity called amp% which is why you've got a problem - indeed, percent signs aren't even allowed in entity names. Basically your input XML file is invalid.

Comment: thanks a lot. so is the ; end of the entity or why &amp; is allowed?